# How to fully fontify latex snippets including subscript and superscript within org-mode

Tags: latex, font-lock, org-mode

I have many latex snippets delimited by `$` inside my org notes. I recently discovered `org-highlight-latex-and-related`, which highlights latex snippets a certain face. However, I want to also apply the specially subscript/superscript faces, which shift the face up and diminish the size, as this helps distinguish things visually. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The main workhorse here is the following:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
               (font-lock-add-keywords nil tex-font-lock-keywords-3)))
```

In addition, I had to customize the subscript, superscript, and tex-math faces to get this effect:

[image]

You can customize the faces to get them to look how you like.

---

I also found that I had to remove the org-table face in order to get the math stuff to appear inside of tables:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
               (font-lock-remove-keywords
                nil
                '(("^[  ]*\\(\\(|\\|\\+-[-+]\\).*\\S-\\)"
                   (1 'org-table t))))))
```

Comment: Pityingly adding `tex-font-lock-keywords-3` to the font lock keywords of orgmode also marks the `u` in `_underlined_ ` as subscript. Calling `font-lock-add-keywords` with the value `t` for the `HOW` argument does also not help in that respect.

Comment: Note also that `tex-mode` uses a smaller shifted font for sub- and superscripts in emacs 26.1. Therefore your answer solves the problem of the OP by default if one does not take the issue in my first comment into account.